# Require title for pages

Tags: pages, title

Is there a way to force users to write a page title before publishing? I have found example of requiring post titles, but not page titles.

Comment: Can you show the examples you found for posts? Posts and pages are more or less the same.

Comment: Yes, this plugin seems to do the job for posts http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-post-title

Comment: Okey, so that plugin actually only checks the field with javascript, so it's not bulletproof. If that is not an issue, you can edit that plugin with one word to change it from posts to pages. If you need it for both posts and pages, you can just add one row instead. I'll post it as an answer since it will actually work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with downloading the plugin called [Force Post Title](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-post-title).

Here's the plugin with one row (2 with the comment line) added to the bottom, based on our comments.

What happens is that a small jQuery script is added to the page **Create Post/Page**. The script will check if the title field is empty when the user clicks the submit button.

Since this is such a small plugin, you could easily modify it and copy it to your functions.php. That way, you won't have to edit an existing plugin which will give you a headache once you update it later on.

*I should also mention that I found something (a filter) that could work in [wp-includes/post.php, row 2489](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2489). I did some quick testing without any results though.*

```
/*
Plugin Name: Force Post Title
Plugin URI: http://appinstore.com
Description: Forces user to assign a Title to a post before publishing 
Author: Jatinder Pal Singh
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://appinstore.com/
*/ 
function force_post_title_init() 
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function force_post_title() 
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
  echo "
  jQuery('#publish').click(function(){
        var testervar = jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]')
        .find('#title');
        if (testervar.val().length < 1)
        {
            jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]').css('background', '#F96');
            setTimeout(\"jQuery('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');\", 100);
            alert('POST TITLE is required');
            setTimeout(\"jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');\", 100);
            return false;
        }
    });
  ";
   echo "</script>\n";
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_post_title_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_title');
// Add this row below to get the same functionality for page creations.
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_post_title');
```

Answer (score 1):

I just modified @hampusn answer a bit to make the integration better. Instead of using an `alert()` it puts a nicely formatted box under the title.

It wraps the jQuery code with the standard `.ready()` function.

I also only wanted to do it for a certain custom post type so I left the snippet in but you can just remove the `$post_type` check if future readers don't need this.

Finally I wrapped the validation message in `_()`. You could theoretically customise this per post type if you wanted to reassign it within the main `if` statement.

```
function rtp_force_post_title_init() 
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function rtp_force_post_title( $post ) 
{
  $post_type = get_post_type();
  $validation_message = _("The title field must be filled out.");

  if('exhibitor' === $post_type) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#publish').click(function(){
        var testervar = jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]').find('#title');
        if (testervar.val().length < 1)
        {
          setTimeout(\"jQuery('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');\", 100);
          var validator_snippet = '<div style=\"padding: 10px; color: #fff; margin-top: -3px; background: #F55E4F;\">" . $validation_message . "</div>';                    
          jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]').find('#titlewrap').append(validator_snippet);          
          setTimeout(\"jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');\", 100);
          return false;
        }
      });
    });\n";
    echo "</script>\n";
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rtp_force_post_title_init' );
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'rtp_force_post_title' );
```