# Prohibit saving a post without providing a title

Tags: posts

How to prevent saving a post without providing a title?

Right now it's possible.

I want to prevent that.

How to achieve this task?

Comment: May be this post could help you?

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65137/require-title-for-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps these plugins will help you:

### [Mandatory fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mandatory-fields/)

This plugin is responsible for making certain fields mandatory before publishing any post in wordpress.

[image]

### [Force Post Title](http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-post-title/)

This is simple plugin which forces the users to write POST title in Add New Post page.

[image]

They both seem to prevent the posting only via JavaScript validation in the backend. If you want to restrict creating posts on the backend side you might want to look into these hooks:

- [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)
- [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I wanted, but I think I can use it while I find something better.