# How to make content as required in custom post type?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, themes

I created custom post type **Testimonials** and made the title required using the code in this link:

[Require title for pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65137/require-title-for-pages)

Now I applied the code in order to make the content required, and it works fine.

**Just** when I click Publish button and editor is empty, an alert message appears at the top of the screen that the content is required.

But **here is the problem:** when I enter some content and click Publish button, the alert message displayed again.

Here is the used code:

```php
function force_testimonials_post_content_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function force_testimonials_post_content() {
    if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'testimonials' ) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "
        jQuery('#publish').click(function() {
            var contentvar = jQuery('[id^=\"postdivrich\"]')
                                .find('.mce-container-body');
            if (contentvar.val().length < 1) {
                jQuery('[id^=\"postdivrich\"]').css('background', '#fff3cd');

                setTimeout(\"jQuery('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');\", 100);

                alert('TESTIMONIAL POST CONTENT IS REQUIRED');

                setTimeout(\"jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');\", 100);
                    
                return false;
            }
        });
        ";
        echo "</script>\n";
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_testimonials_post_content_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_testimonials_post_content');
 // Add this row below to get the same functionality for page creations.
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_testimonials_post_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

the content_save_pre filter. It checks the post type of the current post and ensures that the content field is not empty. If the content field is empty, the function calls wp_die() to display an error message and stop the post from being saved.

Note: Make sure to replace "custom_post_type" with the actual name of your custom post type. Also, you can modify the error message to fit your needs.

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'validate_custom_post_type_content' );
function validate_custom_post_type_content( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'custom_post_type' === $post->post_type && empty( $content ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'The content field is required for this custom post type. Please enter some content and try again.' ) );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: useful answer , this code working fine , but there is a warning appear in top of screen says: `Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\repo\wp-content\plugins\consulty-core\custom-posts\testimonials\testimonials.php on line 285` , consulty-core is a plugin I created for this theme includes custom posts and custom widget.  @vijay-rathod

Comment: the warning line appear when open "add new testimonials" screen  , then disappear after publish post